# Change UIColor of Backgound Image from brown to using RGB Colors

Tags: ipad, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using a image Which is darkbrown in color, Now i would like to change the image color to light yellow using RGB Values Programmatically without changing the image.

Thanks  in advance

Comment: Show us what you have tried first. It's also unclear: do you have a monochrome brown image or one that is tinted brown? Opaque or with an alpha channel? You need to supply a lot more information.

Comment: Does your image contain just this single color? If so, why don't you just replace it with a simple UIView showing the right color? If it does contain a complex image however, things get a bit more complicated... So please tell us a bit more about the precise circumstances. Thanks!

Comment: @ConradShultz : Thank u, no it is not tinted it is a dark brown with some stripes it almost is like a Furniture  color,

Comment: @Toastor : Thank u for the reply, It is not a single color, can u say me how to upload the picture, so that u may get a clear idea and give me the best solution, Thank U.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have an application in our MAC called "DigitalColor Meter". We can use this application into our application to get the color code for RGB.

Steps:

1)   Open DigitalColor Meter application in MAC, can use spot light for easy search.
2)   Keep the required mode to "RGB as Percentage"
3)   Using the mouse pointer go to the required color on the screen.
4)   Note down the RGB values in percentage.
5)   In our code you can use the method

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.663 green:0.855 blue:0.341 alpha:1]
```

convert percentage values into fractions. like 53.5% will become 0.535. Use the respective RGB values in the code, and alpha value must be 1.

Run the application, you will get the exact color required.

Comment: Thanks a lot got my O/P Its Working

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I didn't know about the MAC APP DigitalColor Meter.  I've been manually converting the RGB integers to their percentages.